# Arduino + SIM900: Identify if call is received?

Tags: arduino

I try to find command to identify if call is received and when user press any button of number on their phone. I use arduino + sim900A + Ethernet. I try alot but still no see command to do that. Are there any way exit ? If you know, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AT + CLCC will get back number to know status of recipient